# Registry key js.debugger.use.chrome.extension is not defined

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, liveedit, jetbrains-hub

When i tried to install plugin Live edit in PHPStorm, and run it by debugging i get this error
Registry key js.debugger.use.chrome.extension is not defined. I don't know what's the problem with it.

Comment: would you like to help with what have you tried so far :) ?

Comment: Please check the Registry (Help > Find action > Registry), do you have this option after all?

Comment: could you check if it's still an issue for you after updating to 2022.2?